# "Attach File" button enabled although "Send Message" button is disabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I have sent an application for a job in Careers. Now if I enter the "Messages" section and go to "Sent - Applications", I can see that below my application there's a grayed out text area to type a reply, together with the "You must wait until the employer responds to your application" message. All OK and logical.

The strange thing is that although the "Send Message" button is disabled as one would expect, the "Attach File" button is enabled and working (the browser's file selection dialog appears):

> [image]

This looks like a bug to me... or has it any real purpose?

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Comment: Might be difficult to disable that button, but we'll have a look.

Comment: @Max yeah, since it's not really a button you'll have to "fake" the disabled style. But what about simply hiding the button in case the user can't respond? Won't be 100% consistent with the rest of the form, but will still achieve the goal.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Indeed, that would do the trick. It would be as simple as `<span id="attach-file" ng-if="canSendMessage(thread)">`

Comment: @Konamiman SE use ASP.NET without AngularJS afaik, but yeah that's the general idea.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It seems that AngularJS is indeed used for Careers. My suggestion is based on the actual source code of the page. :-)

Comment: Oh my, one never stop learning. Pretty sure they didn't always use it, only @Max can tell for sure. :)

Comment: We've been using Angular for quite a while now on various (not all) pieces of the Careers page, and the messaging interface is indeed one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, we've added a fix to hide the "Attach File" button when the user can't respond to the message in its current state:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Just nitpicking, but the "Send Message" button gets highlighted when hovered even when disabled, can this also be removed? (i.e. it will stay gray when hovered :))